# Disable click event on ant table

Tags: reactjs

I want, when i will click on `Action` column, on each link from there, to stop apply

```
onClick: () => {
  {
    console.log('log')
  }
```

Now if you click on row the event acts. Here is my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-booth-vlgdu

Comment: @Sumanth Madishetty, do you now how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Change your **action** object to use **e.stopPropagation()**. The following applies on "Invite" link. In case you want it for the entire column, then add it to its span tag( with reference to your sandbox).

Modify the **action** object to the following

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-shtern-ct0n8

```
const columns = [
  --------------------------------
  --------------------------------
  {
    title: "Action",
    key: "action",
    render: (text, record) => (
      <span>
        <a
          style={{ marginRight: 16 }}
          onClick={e => {
            e.stopPropagation();
          }}
        >
          Invite {record.name}
        </a>
        <a>Delete</a>
      </span>
    )
  }
];
```

Comment: but how to change in this case: https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-wind-zh8y9, even i change to: `   <Popconfirm onClick={e => {
          e.stopPropagation()
        }} title="Sure to delete?" onConfirm={() => handleDelete(record.key)}>
          <a>Delete</a>
        </Popconfirm>,` it not work. The event work when i choose `cancel` or `ok`

Comment: here your adding it explicitly  onConfirm={() => this.handleDelete(record.key)

Comment: what is the solution?

Comment: @AskMen What exactly do you want? I quite solved the one in the question. Not understanding the current use case

Comment: i want to know how yo apply `stopPropagation()` in his case: codesandbox.io/s/tender-wind-zh8y9 . Now when i click on popup after clicking `delete`, the stopPropagation() doesnt work

Comment: you want to avoid that console.log and also open the popup?

Comment: when i will click on delete (confirm button), i want to apply the stopPropagation(), but now when i click,  the event also works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209370/discussion-between-askmen-and-sv12).

Comment: click on delete, after that will appear a popup, and when you click on `ok` or `cancel`, the event also works (in console). How to avoid this? This was my question

Comment: pass the event object along Popconfirm **onConfirm={e => this.handleDelete(record.key, e)}** and inside handleDelete use                   e.stopPropagation(); . Check this https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-sun-jkx15

Comment: Yes, this is what i wanted

Answer (score 0):

I was following along with this as a base and came up with this code.

```html
render: (tracking_number) => {
          return (
          <span>
            <Button type="primary" onClick={(e)=>{this.buttonHandler(tracking_number,e)}}>{tracking_number}</Button>
          </span>
        )}
```

Then in my button handler function I had the stop propagation line.

```html
buttonHandler = (trackingNumber,e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log("BUTTON FIRED:",trackingNumber);
  }
```

In the handler I can do any number of things. In this case i'm going to pass the tracking number to a redux state reducer to display the information returned.

Answer (score -1):

This will do what you want

```
render: (text, record) => (
     <span onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}>
        <a style={{ marginRight: 16 }}>Invite {record.name}</a>
        <a>Delete</a>
     </span>
)
```

Comment: but how to change in this case:    https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-wind-zh8y9, even i change to: ` <Popconfirm onClick={e => { e.stopPropagation() }} title="Sure to delete?" onConfirm={() => handleDelete(record.key)}> <a>Delete</a> </Popconfirm>,` it not work. The event work when i choose cancel or ok